# Applying a class on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works well

```
     for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
         $('#boxes').append('<textarea onKeyUp="saveanswers()" class="input-sm" >')
     }
```

However the class 'input-sm' is not applied because this function is on document ready.

How can I get around this?

EDIT:

This code creates 3 text areas. The class 'input-sm' should style the boxes in a certain way.  However because this function happens on document ready, the styling does not get applied. How can I resolve this

EDIT 2:

I have been able to fix the problem however the div 'boxes' sits behind other items EVEN with a high z-index

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery 'on' method: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hmm, there must be another problem. Even if you add a css-class later, the styles get applied. 
can you provide some more html oder javascript-code for clearifying?

Comment: *Styling* (from CSS) should get applied.  If it doesn't then you have an error in your CSS.  Events and javascript may not (if it has already been bound before these elements are added.  See @Billy Moat's comment and `.on` method to get around that.  If you are applying styling via javascript or somethign crazy then don't - put it in a CSS file and it should "just work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the *preferred* method for appending elements to the DOM. Notice that in my example, I create a `jQuery` object, wrapping a `<textarea/>` element, which then allows me to call jQuery functions on the object; in this instance: `keyup` and `addClass`

**Example**

```
for(var index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
    $("#boxes").append(
        $("<textarea/>")
            .addClass("input-sm")
            .keyup(function() { saveanswers(); })
    );
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ptmzS/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for instance

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/55/)**

```
$( document ).ready()
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
         $('#boxes').append('<textarea onKeyUp="saveanswers()" class="input-sm'+i+'" >')
     }
}
```

**css**

```
.input-sm1
{
    background-color:blue;
}
.input-sm2
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.input-sm3
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be conflict in your JS because your code is correct. 
I did a test and it worked:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){

  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $("#boxes").append('<textarea onKeyUp="saveanswers()" class="input-sm" >');
  }

  console.log( $("textarea.input-sm").length ); // 3 

})
</script>

<div id="boxes">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</div>
```

Try not to use '"onKeyUp="saveanswers()"', leaving the "polluted" code, as you're already using jQuery, do a bind (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

```
$("textarea.input-sm").keyup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
});
```